# How to delete a file on a method exit in java?

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I am trying to figure out how to make sure a temporary file that gets created in a method gets deleted by the time the method returns.  I have tried `file.deleteOnExit();`, but that is for when the program stops, not the method.  I have also tried a `try` and `finally` block.  Is using a `finally` block the only way to achieve this?

```
public String example(File file) {
    // do some random processing to the file here
    file.canWrite();
    InputStream() is = new FileInputStread(file);
    // when we are ready to return, use the try finally block
    try {
        return file.getName();
    } finally {
        is.close();
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

I think it looks ugly.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Why can't you delete the file right before the return statement?

Comment: whats wrong with closing and then deleting the file in finally block ?

Comment: @BackSlash I could, but I want to know how to do this on a method exit.

Comment: @StephenD: isn't the `return` statement typically the end of the method?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel not when using `finally`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was mentioned by @BackSlash in your specific case you can just remove file just before return:

```
file.delete();
return "File processed!";
```

However in common case if code inside try block can throw exception your approach looks fine. You can also use Aspect Oriented Programming (e.g. using AspectJ) but it looks like overkill in your case.

You can also improve your code by using nice new feature of Java 7. Each instance of `Closable` will be closed in the end of `try` block, e.g.:

```
try (
    InputStream in = ...
) {
    // read from input stream.
}

// that's it. You do not have to close in. It will be closed automatically since InputStream implements Closable.
```

So, you can create class `AutoDeletableFile` that wraps `File` and implements `Closable`. The `close()` method should delete the file. In this code will work exactly as yours:

```
try (
    AutoDeletableFile file = new AutoDeletableFile("myfile.txt");
) {
    // deal with file
}
// do nothing here. The file will be deleted automatically since its close() method actually deletes the file.
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's what `finally` is for.

Of course, in Java7 you can write an `AutoCloseable` implementation that does the deleting for you and use try-with-resources instead.

Comment: Can you point me to a reference for the auto-close feature **deleting** a temp file? This is the first time I have heard of that....

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 7 you can achieve this by using java.lang.AutoCloseable interface. Details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html.

If not then finally is the best and widely used approach for closing/cleaning resources.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try delete the file at the end of the method (the last line)? This will delete the file right before the method exits if I understand correctly?

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
file.delete();
```